# Simple and easy way to permanently mount remote folder

Tags: mount, php, sshfs

We are planning to replace all our Windows Machine (around 25) of PHP development team to ubuntu and we found everything perfect here however, we have two major problems as we work in team, we do development on remote Linux server and we need to access remote folder on local machine

**All major PHP editor does not allow to open file from bookmarked folder or remote folder mapped using connect to server options, it does not show at all.**

To solve this problem we are trying to map folders using sshfs and we used many ways but we are not able to permanently map the folder, every time we restart it looses the mount

we also tried to use tutorial here http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=84

this is working and creates a folder for mapping but it throws permission error and does not show any contents.

We also tried to bookmark map using sshfs but bookmark does not work after reboot

Can any one suggest best and simple way to permanently mount the folder or better way to access remote folder?
 or 
Can anyone suggest best approach to do a PHP development with a team on remote Linux server and client machine being ubuntu?

Comment: Why not use a source version control? (eg. [Git](http://git-scm.com/))

Answer (score 1):

I would say SSHFS was intended more for ad-hoc usage rather than permanent connections.

The right tool is probably NFS (Network File System). Information about setting this up in Ubuntu can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

Comment: Please include details from the link as if the linked site were to go down, the answer would not be as useful to future visitors.

Comment: Hi Tried using NFS and it seems promising

Answer (score 0):

Use **git** or any other version control system to

- Pull code from the server
- Do changes locally
- Push the changed files back to the server

Comment: We cannot use git due to few reason, our policy does not allow to upload code to any remote server and also we do development on same single Linux server, everyone has their own shell access to same server, they use CVS check on same server and do all development there, this way we dont need to create multiple development environemnt

Comment: HI tried using NFS and looks okay, and after reboot I could reconnect using bookmark though it takes some time to list folders. however, it does not allow me to edit files, it shows lock, on server NFS shared is standard no specific configuration. can any one advise on possible problem ?